# Can I save the stream of my same page c#?

Tags: c#, stream

My site has many labels loaded in the Load event.
After the page is loaded I need to get all the html with these new changes.
As I can get it?
I'm programming on the same page.

Comment: Could you rephrase the question (tell it in other words)? It's hard to understand what are you trying to do.

Comment: I need to get the html or the stream of the resulting page.

Answer (score 0):

See various approaches already enumerated here:
[ASP.NET Save HTML Sent to Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/831334/asp-net-save-html-sent-to-browser)

I've personally created an HTTP module for a similar purpose.